# Trying to find a book/story written in 1960's, 70's regarding travelers through a wormhole network

Tags: story-identification, wormhole

It has the travelers in a spacecraft who are on the first mission through a wormhole. They realize that there is a network of wormholes and they are artificial, They agree to journey further as they try to discover who created the network. They travel from solar system to solar system, from close to the galactic center to the far edge of the galaxy.

Answer (score 6):

[The Avatar by Poul Anderson](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1234701.The_Avatar) (1978)?

> In the immeasurable past a mysterious alien race known as The Others left mankind a challenging legacy, a 'gate' to the unexplored reaches of the stars. Humanity has utilized the gate to painstakingly colonize the Phoebus star system but has left the rest of the galaxy unexplored. In the midst of turbulent political upheaval on Earth, the exploratory ship Emissary leaves through the gate on a voyage of discovery. ...

Comment: II think this might be it. Need to re-read it to verify if it is, but it certainly sounds like it.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Contact by Carl Sagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_%28novel%29)?  It's from 1985, but other than that it hits the points you mention.

In the book, humanity receives an alien message which is decrypted to reveal a set of blueprints.  Earth's governments build the machine and put a multinational crew inside.  Once activated, the machine sends the travellers through a series of wormholes, until they reach the center of the galaxy.

Comment: No afraid not, the wormhole was set in the solar system not on earth, and no aliens had contacted them at anytime through the story.

Answer (score 3):

Another candidate is [Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_%28novel%29) by Fred Pohl. It's dated in your range, 1977.

I don't recall if the characters travel to the center of the galaxy or to the far edge. But it does have a system of wormholes left behind by a vanished civilization and poorly understood by humans. The focus is more on the psychological consequences of the high-risk work of exploring the wormholes than on the discoveries made in the exploration.

Comment: I remember the the Heechee series well.